# What's the difference between Google Cloud Scheduler and GAE cron job?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

After reading the docs

- cloud scheduler - https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/
- GAE cron job -
  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml
- cloud function pub/sub trigger -
  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub

I think they are mostly the same.

I can use `GAE cron job` + `pub/sub` + `cloud function` to implement the same functions which `cloud scheduler` has.

In my understanding, it seems there are some differences between them:

1. Cloud Scheduler can be more convenient to adjust frequency. To update the frequency of `GAE cron job`, you must update the config, like `schedule: every 1 hours` of `cron.yaml` and redeploy.
2. There is no need to implement the cron job architecture(integrate `GAE`, `GAE cron service`, `pub/sub`, `cloud function`, etc..) by yourself which means you don't need to write code for combining them together anymore.

Am I correct? Or, any other differences?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're right in that the Google Cloud Scheduler is kind of an evolution of the GAE cron job mechanism to make it more user-friendly and flexible. You can see that they are still related since the [Cloud Scheduler doc](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/) specifies:

> To use Cloud Scheduler your project must contain an App Engine app
> that is located in one of the supported regions. If your project does
> not have an App Engine app, you must create one.

Historically, GAE cron job was the only cron service offered by the platform. You could only target a GAE handler to receive the request from cron. From there you could indeed perform actions like like publish on pub/sub, call an HTTP Cloud Function or launch a dataflow job, but you always had to deploy a GAE service to handle it, which wasn't optimal.

The new Cloud Scheduler makes it more straightforward to use with Pub/Sub, Cloud Functions but also any publicly available HTTP endpoint (may be on-premise). And of course App Engine handlers. More targets may be added in the future for more use-cases.

Finally, as you mentioned, the API exposed to manage it decouples it from App Engine and its cron.yaml file and makes it easier to create and update cron jobs dynamically.

Comment: Thank you. I had the same question. I have a GAE app and was wondering whether to use the cron.yaml approach with GAE, or the more general Cloud Scheduler. Cloud Scheduler looks more flexible and like it has a better interface for managing multiple cron jobs, and this answer really helps me understand their evolution and why they both exist. I'm going to use the Cloud Scheduler.